# Two Singly-Linked-List Sharing Same Node & Destructor Deleting Same Memory Twice

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

Linked List 1: 3->6->9->15->30
Linked List 2: 10->15->30

Linked List 1 & 2 intersects at 15 and shares the same nodes 15 and 30.

I have two linked list and I am searching for the intersecting node, which is 15. Before the program ends, the linked list destructor is called. The first destructor call frees up memory without any problem. The second list then tries to delete its own node of 15. The destructor is trying to delete already freed up memory, which causes the program to crash. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Don't cross-link your lists. Short of that, use `std::shared_ptr`'s and let the runtime sort it out.

Comment: Please share code and error.

Comment: Please provide the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: If you want the nodes to be shared (similarly to Lisp lists) that's what `shared_ptr` is for. If you want the lists to be independent, don't share nodes between them.

Comment: uset `boost::shared_ptr` with `make_shared`

Answer (score 1):

First, let me point out that your lists shouldn't in general contain the same node. If you need shared objects between lists, save pointers or references to the object in the node instead of sharing the node itself.

If you must share the node itself, what you need is [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting).

In essence, what you do is keep track of the number (in a variable) of pointers or references to a particular object, and free the memory only when the number goes to 0, indicating the object can no longer be reached and should be freed.

To do reference counting with the STL, you use [`shared_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/), which is in the STL since C++11.

```
struct node
{
    node(const data_t&);
    data_t data;
    std::shared_ptr<node> next;
};

auto head1 = std::make_shared(some_data1);
auto head2 = std::make_shared(some_data2);
head1->next = std::make_shared(some_data);
head2->next = head1->next;
//note that you do NOT copy the raw pointer, you must copy the shared_ptr itself

head1.reset();  //destroys some_data1 but not some_data
head2.reset();  //destroys some_data2 and some_data
```